# Is it possible to connect to different client via reverse SSH tunnel through different subdomain?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel

So when you're using reverse SSH tunnel and you only have one client, it'll be simply enough to run `ssh -R 1999:localhost:22 remote@server` and then `ssh -p 1999 localhost` on the server. But how about you have multiple clients?

Is it possible to create a wildcard subdomain for SSH so the client can connect to a unified port like `ssh -R 1999:localhost:22 remote@user1.server`, `ssh -R 1999:localhost:22 remote@user2.server` and on the server we can access to different clients by `ssh -p 1999 user1.server`, `ssh -p 1999 user2.server`.

Comment: This much older question asks to solve almost the same underlying challenge, though by different means: https://serverfault.com/q/402852/250204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have multiple destinations proxied through a single ip+port connection, as SSH  clients do not indicate which server they wish to speak to. What you suggest is certainly achievable (by assigning new addresses for each name) with significant administrative overhead.

But is is not probably not desirable. If everyone is supposed to connect to the forwarded machines through that server (called *bastion*) anyway, you got more options than just plain ports.

E.g., you can place the connections to the forwarded machines in a folder on the server:

```
ssh -R /minion/user1.example:localhost:22 user1.example@bastion.example
ssh -R /minion/user2.example:localhost:22 user2.example@bastion.example
# or even
ssh -R /minion/$(hostname -f):localhost:22 $(hostname -f)@bastion.example
```

As every socket is named after the server it is connected to, one config works for all:

```
Host *.example
  ProxyCommand ssh bastion.example netcat -U /chroot/minion/%h
```

And the command to use it looks clean & simple:

```
ssh user@user1.example
ssh user@user2.example
```

See `man 5 ssh_config` for an explanation on `%h` and `%n`, one of which you likely want to use. Also mind the `StreamLocalBindUnlink` option, as you do not want the setup to fail if sockets already exist.